# Change ident casing in macro?

Tags: rust, macros

In my ecs, I successefuly implemented a rust macro that takes any number of components, and create an iterator on each components tuple of the given components that are on the same entity.

Now, in the macro, I am creating a struct with fields that are named after the given components. As the components are camel cased, the struct field are too.

How could I convert them to snake case ? The components are passed as `comp:ident` in the macro.

I know there are ways to allow non snake case, but I failed to make it work and I dont think it is the way to go.

Finally, I would also want in the future to pass generics, or composed types to be used, so I would also need to convert the `Rc<Position>` to `rc_of_position` or something.

If any of you want to check the code, here it is (it's still a bit messy and needs to be optimized) : https://github.com/VirgileHenry/Foundry/blob/main/src/ecs/component_iterator.rs

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`paste`](https://docs.rs/paste/1.0.11/paste/#case-conversion).

```
use paste::paste;

macro_rules! make_struct {
    ($name: ident) => {
        paste! {
            #[derive(Debug, Default)]
            struct [< $name:camel >] {

            }
        }
    }
}

make_struct!(foo_bar);

fn main() {
    let d = FooBar::default();
    println!("{d:?}");
}
```